# Loading properties using @Value into a BeanFactory object using @Bean in Spring Boot

Tags: spring

Can anyone help me with a Spring Boot problem?

I want to create a factory bean as part of my application context but I want to be able to instantiate it with injected property values. However it seems that Spring will load FactoryBeans before anything else as demonstrated here:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AbstractFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ListFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class TestClass
{
    @Value("${test.value}")
    String value;

    @Bean
    public Object test1()
    {
        System.out.println("test.value=" + value );

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        ListFactoryBean factory = new ListFactoryBean();
        factory.setSourceList(list);

        return factory;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(TestClass.class, args);
    }
}
```

When run with

```
java -Dtest.value=HELLO -jar myTest.jar
```

It loads in the value correctly:

```
test.value=HELLO
```

However, when I specify that the bean to be loaded is in fact a factory bean, and run it in the same way:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AbstractFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ListFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class TestClass
{
    @Value("${test.value}")
    String value;

    @Bean
    public AbstractFactoryBean test1()
    {
        System.out.println("test.value=" + value );

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        ListFactoryBean factory = new ListFactoryBean();
        factory.setSourceList(list);

        return factory;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(TestClass.class, args);
    }
}
```

The value is null because it hasn't been injected yet.

```
test.value=null
```

Is there any way around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring often has to query bean definitions for the type of object they produce. Factory beans are always problematic because they can cause dependency cascades in a futile attempt to resolve all dynamic information available before asking for the type.

I think `ListFactoryBean` is insufficiently precise about its product type (`getObjectType()` can only return a non-generic `List.class`). You might be able to write your own factory that is parameterized with the correct generic type. Or you might get away with just declaring the `@Bean` to return a `FactoryBean<List<String>`.

Another tip is to move the `@Bean` definition to a separate class (e.g. a nested static one) so that it can be instantiated independently of the rest of the application context. E.g.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class TestClass
{

  protected static class NestedConfiguration {

    @Value("${test.value}")
    String value;

    @Bean
    public FactoryBean<Properties> test1()
    {
        System.out.println("test.value=" + value );
        // ...
        return factory;
    }

  }
    ...

}
```

Not really a Boot question this one so you might consider changing the tags.

Comment: Fair point about the tag. Have changed it now. The ListFactoryBean was only used to demonstrate that the factory bean gets loaded first. The FactoryBean that im using returns `Properties.class` as the object type. I've tried moving the `@Bean` to a nested static class but it complains that the annotation cant be placed there. Could you provide an example?

Comment: Edited with example nested configuration. Maybe if you a whole simplified project somewhere accessible like github it would help to get to the real heart of what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Take look at [Empowering your apps with Spring Boot's property support](http://spring.io/blog/2013/10/30/empowering-your-apps-with-spring-boot-s-property-support)

There is new annotation `@EnableConfigurationProperties` in [Spring Boot Actuator](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/spring-boot-actuator/README.html)

> The Spring Environment is a collection of name-value pairs taken from (in order of decreasing precedence)
>
> 1) the command line,
>
> 2) the external configuration file,
>
> 3) System properties,
>
> 4) the OS environment.

There is also possible to define application properties (external configuration) in YAML format.

Comment: Yeah I've used the `@EnableConfigurationProperties` but it appears they dont get loaded before a FactoryBean. So if you try and use any of these properties to inject into a FactoryBean then they are null as they havent been loaded yet